# Why numba and numpy performs differently on inplace operations?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, in-place

Functions decorated with numba **`njit`** which is an alias to **`jit(nopython=True)`** yields different result from **`numpy`** on inplace operations (simple **`@jit(nopython=False)`** also gives different results from `numpy`):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
        from numba import njit

        def npfun(arr):
            arr -= arr[3]

        @njit
        def jitfun(arr):
            arr -= arr[3]

        arr1 = np.ones((6,2))
        arr2 = arr1.copy()

        npfun(arr1)
        jitfun(arr2)

        arr1 == arr2

Out[1]: array([[ True,  True],
               [ True,  True],
               [ True,  True],
               [ True,  True],
               [False, False],
               [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

It looks like **`numpy`** evaluates rhs and passes it as a copy, while **`numba`** treats rhs as a view. Is there any technical reason to do so?

`numpy 1.13.3`
`numba 0.35`

Comment: Yes, `numpy` operations tend to be buffered.  It shouldn't matter whether the underlying code iterates from start to end or the reverse.  Conceptually all elements are operated on in parallel.

Comment: I haven't worked with `numba` but it looks like it is doing the equivalent of `for i in range(6): arr[i] -= arr[3]`, which would be different if it iterated in the other direction, `range(5,-1,-1)`.

Comment: Related to my earlier question (and maybe indirectly my fault!): https://stackoverflow.com/q/43151152/541686

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation you're doing:

```
arr -= arr[3]
```

used to be undefined behavior in NumPy. It only became defined very recently, in [NumPy 1.13.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html#ufunc-behavior-for-overlapping-inputs), released [June 7th this year](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.13.0). The new, defined behavior always acts as if it makes copies of all inputs, although it tries to avoid actually making copies when it can detect that it doesn't need to.

It looks like Numba does not currently attempt to mimic the new behavior, either because of how new it is, or because of Numba-specific concerns.

Comment: I did not know about this, and also that this behavior was guaranteed. While I still think that it will be better to leave it as undefined that others would not rely on, and not to see it during code review. Actually, I'm in some confusion because mentally I agree more with numba, but I see practical reasons of numpy-devs. In any case I think this bug magnet form should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

#### Workaround

It will help Numba if you use an explicit in-place operation, with `out` argument, instead of augmented assignment: replace

```
arr -= arr[3]
```

with

```
np.subtract(arr, arr[3], out=arr)
```

This makes the jitted version (though with @jit, not @njit) perform identically to the NumPy version. Notably, an attempt to @njit this function will now fail, telling you than njit cannot handle the `out` argument.

I see you already [opened an issue on this](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2644), so there's a chance that the handling of augmented assignments will be changed to match NumPy.

#### Why this happens

As hpaulj said, the Numba output is equivalent to looping over the rows of the array. A Python JITter cannot do anything with C code underlying NumPy; it needs Python to work with. The reason that NumPy methods are supported (to some extent) is that Numba developers went into the trouble of decoding NumPy array operations into explicit Python iteration on scalar objects, which can then be passed to LLVM. From the [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/developer/rewrites.html#the-lower-array-expr-function):

> - Synthesize a Python function that implements the array expression: This new Python function essentially behaves like a Numpy ufunc, returning the result of the expression on scalar values in the broadcasted array arguments. The lowering function accomplishes this by translating from the array expression tree into a Python AST.
> - Compile the synthetic Python function into a kernel: At this point, the lowering function relies on existing code for lowering ufunc and DUFunc kernels, calling `numba.targets.numpyimpl.numpy_ufunc_kernel()` after defining how to lower calls to the synthetic function.
>
> The end result is similar to loop lifting in Numba’s object mode.

The aforementioned [`numpy_ufunc_kernel`](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/targets/npyimpl.py#L296) gathers indices and *iterates* over them. If the object being iterated over mutates in the process of iteration, that makes things hairy.

Comment: I found `arr -= arr[3] ` while reviewing some code, and was surprised how `numpy` treats this (also I did not know that this behaviour is guaranteed since `numpy 1.13` as @user2357112 said). Then I checked this in `numba` and the obtained results fits better my mentality, but because they are different I've opened a ticket. Thinking about this after 1 week, I'm still confused, honestly, I see practical reasons for python-dev to implement that in this way but for me it was better to leave it undefined.

Comment: The NumPy output fits my expectation, because NumPy allows us to think of the array operations as atomic. It's "take the [3, :] slice and subtracts it from the entire array at once" , no loops.